# Why is SoftwareSerial not present in Arduino 1.5.8?

Tags: eclipse, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, software-serial

I am using Arduino IDE 1.5.8 with Eclipse and I tried to import SoftwareSerial. However, the library does not seem to be present in the Arduino IDE. Also, as a substitute (from various blogs) I tried using/importing **NewSoftSerial**. However, I get the following error everytime:

```
#error NewSoftSerial has been moved into the Arduino core as of version 1.0. Use SoftwareSerial instead.
```

I am completely stuck with this. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has been moved the avr specific libraries.

see: ..\arduino-1.5.8\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial..

Note. NewSoftSerial been integrated into as the IDE as, and replacing, the old SoftwareSerial.

Comment: So do I have to import the library folder for it to work? It does work with the Arduino IDE itself, just doesn't work with Eclipse IDE. I am confused with what I have to do.

Comment: I'm not an Eclipse user. However, I know there are different implementations of the Arduino Plugin. I see reference of a V2.2 that supports IDE 1.5.7+. Perhaps that will work. However, I suspect it may not support the platform specific libraries. I see configuration console for the plugin that you fill into specify the libraries. But don't see for the Platform (aka AVR vs. SAM). Hence you can modify your make file to include these specific paths. Or use an explicit path with the file name of the .h file. Or move the library of interest to the root of the libraries.

Comment: I imported the SoftwareSerial library to eclipse and there is no error of SoftwareSerial not found, but now i get another error when I verify the program. Which is:  `undefined reference to SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial` . I am completely confused now.

Comment: I added the SoftwareSerial.cpp file in the same folder as my .ino file and it did not get me any error. It may have worked. I am still not sure. However, whenever I send a command through the Serial Monitor, eclipse crashes. Hope this atleast helps people who have the same error with SoftwareSerial.